# convert following systemd into upstart for ubuntu 14.04 -- uwsgi emperor mode did not work as expected

Tags: django, ubuntu, nginx, uwsgi, upstart

I have the following script that was given to help me turn on uwsgi at emperor mode.

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-serve-django-applications-with-uwsgi-and-nginx-on-centos-7

I have tweaked it slightly for the below:

```
[Unit]
Description=uWSGI Emperor service

[Service]
ExecStartPre=/bin/bash -c 'mkdir -p /run/uwsgi; chown vagrant:www-data /run/uwsgi'
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/uwsgi --emperor /etc/uwsgi/sites
Restart=always
KillSignal=SIGQUIT
Type=notify
NotifyAccess=all

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

I needed to rewrite this for ubuntu 14.04 hence I wrote the below into `/etc/init/uwsgi.conf`

```
description "uWSGI Emperor service"

## equivalent to wantedby=multi-user.target
start on runlevel [2345]

# create a directory needed by the daemon
pre-start exec /bin/bash -c 'mkdir -p /run/uwsgi; chown vagrant:www-data /run/uwsgi'

exec /usr/local/bin/uwsgi --emperor /etc/uwsgi/sites

respawn
kill signal SIGQUIT
expect stop
```

What was expected:

- `/run/uwsgi` will be created with the ownership as `vagrant:www-data`
- it will have 2 .sock files called `djangoonpy2.sock` and `djangoonpy3.sock`

What I did see:

- `/run/uwsgi` will be created with the ownership as `vagrant:www-data`
- it only has 1 .sock file called `djangoonpy2.sock`

I am runnning ubuntu14.04 using vagrant as a virtual machine.

Please advise.